# query snowflake from jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I query

```
cs = con.cursor()
cs.execute("USE DATABASE DEV_TEST")
cs.execute(r"SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS")
```

it retrieves the data
but if I put a `WHERE` clause it returns nothing

```
cs.execute(r"SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='TESTTABLE'")
```

Can you help me what I'm doing wrong

Note: `TESTTABLE` table exists in a right location

Comment: Are you 100% sure TESTTABLE is not lowercase or something like that  ? Maybe print the query results of `SELECT column_name, table_Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and double check.

Comment: I'm 100% sure  Here it is an output of your query  `COL1 TESTTABLE   
COL2 TESTTABLE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose variable names in double quotes.

https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008aREunSAG/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-snowflake

Comment: I don't see the mention of variables in the question